# Scheduling Push Notification every day in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, notifications, push, onesignal

Im trying to figure it out , that how to schedule a Notification every day at certain time (say 7 am) in C#, can any one Help on this. I'm able to figured the Present time by using "System.Datetime.Now" this. And also another Doubt when i attache this script to a game object and run the game, if the time doesn't match with scheduled time and game was closed. Does we get Notification at scheduled time or we need to run the game in the background. Thank You.

Comment: Please add more information on what exactly you're hoping to do, and what you have already tried. It seems like you're approaching this wrong.

Comment: You might want to consider the .NET [API for Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than rolling your own